# Не работает RewriteRule в .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^api/([^/]*)$ /api/framework.php/$1 [L]
```

Задача состоит в том, чтобы все пути, в которых встречается `/api/...` перенаправлять на `/api/framework.php/...`.

Если при такой конфигурации `.htaccess` файла я обращаюсь к

```
http://hostname/api/user_status
```

то получаю `No input file specified.`.

Но если я напрямую пишу `http://hostname/api/framework.php/user_status`, то скрипт отрабатывает как нужно. В чем может быть проблема?

*из комментариев:*

> Я пытаюсь развернуть проект на тестовом сервере и почему-то этот же код, что я привел в самом начале, работает на основном сервере, но не работает на тестовом

Comment: Ищите различия в конфигурации основного и тестового сервера. Может банально оказаться, что файл .htaccess на тестовом сервере не обрабатывается Апачем.

Comment: вы уверены, что `rewrite_base` на обоих серверах должны совпадать?